# converting a const char to an array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am trying to convert a const char, to a char... here is my code:

```
bool check(const char* word)
{

char *temp[1][50];

temp = word;

return true;
}
```

It is a function with a const char passed in.  I need to convert that const char to a char.  When I run this code now, the compiler throws up this error:

```
dictionary.c:28:6: error: array type 'char *[1][50]' is not assignable
temp = word;
```

How do I correctly complete this conversion?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>
bool check(const char* word)
{
    char temp[51];
    if(strlen(word)>50)
        return false;
    strncpy(temp,word,51);
    // Do seomething with temp here
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ok, great that works, now I need to implement the next part of the program, which is checking if the word stored in temp is a correctly spelled word in the dictionary... To do this I have a global variable that holds the dictionary.  Here is the code that defines it, so you know what I am working with: char *result = NULL;   I need to be able to tell if somewhere in "result"  there is a string = to temp.  It then needs to return true if an identical string is found (meaning the word is spelled correctly) and false otherwise. If you can also help me with this I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @JoshuaMcDonald you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a non-const version, you'll have to copy the string:

```
char temp[strlen(word) + 1];
strcpy(temp, word);
```

Or:

```
char * temp = strdup(word);

if(!temp)
{
    /* copy failed */

    return false;
}

/* use temp */

free(temp);
```